# Idle Heroes - Methods

Tags: idle-heroes

I am currently playing Idle Heroes on iPhone. You are able to "fuse" your heroes to so called methods. But I am unsure, what happens to my heroes when I fuse them.

Of course, every hero I use to fuse will be gone and replaced by the new method. But what happens to his Level, all the items they currently carry, invested dust for his gem? Will the gem has the same level as the base hero, which is used to fuse all those other heroes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first choosen Hero will still be available after fusion. All the rest is gone. 
You will receive some resources you already invested in them back, like in the disassembling.

All equiped stuff will be send to your bagpack.